# "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing" when using input()

Tags: python, input, syntax-error, python-2.x

I have 2 Python scripts which are main_menu.py and inputip.py.

The problem occurs when I press "enter" to be redirected to main_menu.py when my function finishes in inputip.py. The script does not allow me to redirect to main_menu.py instead it shows this error on the Windows command prompt:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\main_menu.py", line 32, in ?
    execfile('C:\python\Inputip.py')
  File "C:\python\Inputip.py", line 11, in ?
    input ("\nSelect enter to proceed back to Main Menu\n")
  File "<string>", line 0
```

^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Here are my codes (main_menu.py):

```
def menu():
#print what options you have
print "Welcome to Simple Network Program"
print " "
print "Please enter a following option to proceed"
print " "
print "2) View Personal IP Address"
print " "
return input ("Select an Option here: ")
loop = 1
choice = 0
while loop == 1:
choice = menu()
if choice == 1:
    execfile('Inputip.py')
elif choice == 5:
    loop = 0
print "Thank you for using the Simple Network Program!"
```

The code (inputip.py):

```
#! /usr/bin/python

# To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
# and open the template in the editor.
import socket
import os
print ("\n\n"+socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))
input ("\nSelect enter to proceed back to Main Menu\n")

execfile('C:\python\main_menu.py')
```

The error seems to be pointing to the execfile. Some advice on the codes would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Please fix your indenting and properly format your traceback

Comment: Furthermore, is there a reason you're using execfile() on different modules? Do you need to run the scripts individually as well? If not, just use import.

Comment: A comment not directly linked to the original question : you should definitely avoid using execfile in almost all cases ! Use objects and methods instead !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using python 3.x (but your question is not tagged as such), don't use input. Use raw_input in stead. It will return strings, so convert them to int first, or do a string comparison. E.g.

```
x = raw_input("Choice")
if x == '1': 
    do_this()
```